# Returning in a DataFrame - Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, conditional-statements, directory

Good morning.

I have a question regarding Python. I have an if where has the conditional and else, the else it renders more than one file and I need to save all information it reads inside a DataFrame, is there a way to do this?

The code I am using:

```
for idx, folder in enumerate(fileLista):
    if folder == 'filename_for_treatment':
        df1 = pd.read_excel(folder, sheet_name = sheetName[idx], skiprows=1)
        df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip()
        tratativaUm = df1[[column information to be used]]

     else:
        df2 = pd.read_excel(folder, sheet_name = sheetName[idx], skiprows=1)
        df2.columns  = df2.columns.str.strip()
        TratativaDois = df2[[column information to be use]]

####assign result of each file received in the else

frames = [tratativaUm, tratativaDois] 
titEmpresa = pd.concat(frames)
```

Can someone help me, is it possible to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by appending your dataframes in a list for example:

```
list_df_tratativaDois = []
for idx, folder in enumerate(fileLista):
    df = pd.read_excel(folder, sheet_name = sheetName[idx], skiprows=1)
    df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
    if folder == 'filename_for_treatment':
        tratativaUm = df[[column information to be used]]
     else:
        list_df_tratativaDois.append(df[[column information to be use]])

titEmpresa = pd.concat([tratativaUm]+list_df_tratativaDois)
```

Note that instead of `df1` and `df2` you can just create a `df` as it was the same `read_excel` and then depending if `folder` is the right one, do a different action on `df`

Comment: I tried to do the same thing, only he is ignoring the files, he reads only the one of the negociadoraA, is there any reason for that to happen?

Comment: @BrendaMoura what is "negociadoraA"?

Comment: Sorry, negociadoraA = tratativaUm

Comment: @BrendaMoura no sure I can answer without more information about `fileLista`. and is your `'filename_for_treatment'` unique? at the end of the day, you want to `concat` one sheet from several excel files and be sure that the one meeting your condition is the first in your final DF?

Comment: Not, 
I have many files that have the xls extension (Excel). 
I need to read all and put in a single DataFrame. The problem is that there is a file that has the header different from the others. The first code that I put in is doing this, my problem is that when it arrives at Else, it is overwriting the files, and I need it to consider all the information.

Comment: I'm starting in Python, sorry for the amount of questioning and thanks for helping me out

Comment: @BrendaMoura no problem, and ok I understand better, but I don't know why it does not work for you if you append all the df not meeting your condition in the `list_df_tratativaDois`. what is the length of  `fileLista` and of `list_df_tratativaDois` after your loop for?

Comment: Good morning. 
I'm doing it in an abstract way because I can have more files at some point. 
However, in this specific scenario I have three Excel files (.xls), two are with the same header and one is with the different header. 
Then the FileList has the function of grouping all the .xls files that are found in the folder. 
TratativaUm function to handle the file that has the layout different from the others.

Comment: The list_df_tratativaDois has that it is habito to treat the other files that have the same header, therefore, it is necessary that it creates a DataFrame for each file to read, the same one can not overwrite like the already existing information.

Comment: @BrendaMoura with what you say and your three xls files, what I have called `list_df_tratativaDois` should contain two dfs after your loop `for`,  so `len(list_df_tratativaDois)` should give you 2. If not, it means that you don't go in the `else` part of the code, meaning your condition `if` is met more than one.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. 
Make some changes and download a list by HardCode. 
Should I put a solution somewhere?

Comment: @BrendaMoura if you found a solution, yes answer yourself your question with enough details and accept it to "close" your question but if someone gets the same issue, they can find the solution here :)